# Nagios Host Stacked Graphs

Tags: nagios

I've got several identical front end web servers which are monitored by Nagios for various services and host performance stats (application metrics, memory, cpu etc...). I also use the graph explorer component which I really like. I particularly like the time-stacked graphs to analyse performance of each web server over time, but wondering if there is a way to stack graphs by host. Since these servers all do the same thing, i'd like to view each monitored service stacked by host. So for example: I want to see MongoDB replication lag for each server for the last x days stacked on top of each other in the same graph.

In addition I do not have the option in Graph Explorer for Multi-stacked graphs. The only options available are Top Alerts,Host Health, Service Health, Scalable Performance Graph Time Stacked Performance Graph.

The version of Nagios is: Nagios XI Version : 2012R2.2

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the multi-tasked performance graph, just select the parameter you want compare from each of your servers and add it to the graph, then select the time period and upgrade the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Found something interesting regarding Multistacked graphs here: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/CHANGES-2014.TXT

```
2014R1.0 - 05/13/2014
-------------------------------
[...]
VISUALIZATIONS & FUNCTIONALITY
[...]
- Enhanced Graph Explorer (with Stacked Performance Graphs) -JO
```

So it is entirely possible that Multistacked is a feature of Nagios 2014R1.0 and above. Not necessarily Graph Explorer itself.